# This shows while shutting down my laptop (HP with Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: boot, 18.04, shutdown

While shutting down my laptop, my screen shows this and doesn't shut down, I had to force shutdown it. Any clue, why it's happening?[image: this is the image I'm referring to.]

Comment: i don't have an answer, if at all a supposition: i also experienced this in the last month on my RaspberryPi (running DietPi)... but just once after changing some graphic settings (unfortunately i don't remember exactly which). i had to pull the plug, but after that and the next boot, everything worked normal as it should.

Comment: one advice: try to investigate if it may have to do with some screen settings or graphic-card drivers, etc... **||** one recommendation: describe the problem a little bit more in detail; when you do so, it will be more likely to identify the issue, get an answer and probably even solve it.